# Searching old code that was hosted on tigris.org: svnwcrev-1.0.tar.gz

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tigris

Once upon a time there was the open source collaboration platform tigris.org. Tigris.org will shut down on July 2020 and is not accessible anymore. I need an old file from it for a commercial project:

```
svnwcrev-1.0.tar.gz
svn checkout http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/svn/svnwcrev/trunk svnwcrev --username guest
```

It is a Linux port of the Subversion Tortoise tool SubWCRev. I asked the maintainers of tigris.org already for a copy. Is there anything else I can do to get a copy of the svnwcrev-1.0.tar.gz or does someone has one ?

(Yes, I did google, I also tried archive.org. No, I did not read the manual. Yes, we considered migrating to git ;)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does that tool do anything similar to the [SubWCRev program](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) bundled with TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In collaboration with the subversion mailing list I found a way to replace svnwcrev in our use-case by a single line of shell script.

```
printf '{"%s","%d",""}' \
     $(svn info $1 --show-item=url) \
     $(svn info $1 --show-item=revision)
```

Thanks for your support. $1 refers to the first argument to a shell script, alternatively the $1 it can be replaced by a folder name. You can also leave $1 away, then the current folder is examined.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for a response from cnsupport@collab.net, and maybe forward your question to the users@ Apache Subversion mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a slightly older version of svnwcrev: [https://launchpad.net/~codegear/+archive/ubuntu/release/+sourcefiles/svnwcrev/1.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1/svnwcrev_1.0.orig.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecodegear/+archive/ubuntu/release/+sourcefiles/svnwcrev/1.0-0ubuntu1%7Etrusty1/svnwcrev_1.0.orig.tar.gz). However, it does not support `$WCDATE$`, which was supported by the now-dead svn repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can still download the files if you used Wayback Machine. Nav through the latest saved version and click on the download button you need.
Here is a link to the page I tested this on:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200820045742/https://plug-mirror.rcac.purdue.edu/osdn//storage/g/t/to/tortoisesvn/1.14.0/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.14.0.28885-x64-svn-1.14.0.msi

Answer (score 0):

while searching for an update of svnwcrev, I found that many are searching for the sources. Well, I still had sources from pre 2015, so I created a place in github to share them [svnwcrev sources](https://github.com/FauthD/svnwcrev).